# How to solve Client is not, or no longer, connected. Did you call connect() before login()?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am using prosody xmpp server hosted in aws console i am trying to connect to login with my credentials but everytime i encounter the same error. I am usign smack doe this purpose.i searched through all of git and stackovrflow but couldnot find one

my mainactivity.java

```
private boolean register(final String paramString1,final String paramString2) {
    try {
        XMPP.getInstance().register(paramString1, paramString2);
        return true;

    } catch (XMPPException localXMPPException) {
        localXMPPException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean login(final String user,final String pass,final String username) {
    try {
        XMPP.getInstance().login(user, pass, username);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("liveapp.loggedin"));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            XMPP.getInstance().login(user, pass, username);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("liveapp.loggedin"));

            return true;
        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    public UserLoginTask() {
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... paramVarArgs) {
        String mEmail = "abc";
        String mUsername = "abc";
        String mPassword = "welcome";

        if (register(mEmail, mPassword)) {
            try {
                XMPP.getInstance().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return login(mEmail, mPassword, mUsername);

    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        try {
            if (success) {

                messageListener = new ChatMessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

                        // here you will get only connected user by you

                    }
                };


                packetListener = new StanzaListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processStanza(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {

                        if (packet instanceof Message) {
                            final Message message = (Message) packet;

                            // here you will get all messages send by anybody
                        }
                    }
                };

                chatListener = new ChatManagerListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void chatCreated(Chat chatCreated, boolean local) {
                    }
                };


                try {
                    String opt_jidStr = "abc";

                    try {
                        opt_jid = JidCreate.bareFrom(Localpart.from(opt_jidStr), Domainpart.from(HOST));
                    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String addr1 = XMPP.getInstance().getUserLocalPart(getApplicationContext());
                    String addr2 = opt_jid.toString();
                    if (addr1.compareTo(addr2) > 0) {
                        String addr3 = addr2;
                        addr2 = addr1;
                        addr1 = addr3;
                    }
                    chat = XMPP.getInstance().getThreadChat(getApplicationContext(), addr1, addr2);
                    if (chat == null) {
                        chat = XMPP.getInstance().createChat(getApplicationContext(), (EntityJid) opt_jid, addr1, addr2, messageListener);
                        Log.e(TAG, "chat value single chat 1 :" + chat);
                    } else {
                        chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
                        Log.e(TAG, "chat value single chat  2:" + chat);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                XMPP.getInstance().addStanzaListener(getApplicationContext(), packetListener);
                XMPP.getInstance().addChatListener(getApplicationContext(), chatListener);
                XMPP.getInstance().getSrvDeliveryManager(getApplicationContext());

            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    if (cancel) {
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        try {
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInfo");

    attemptLogin();
}
```

}

XMPP.java file

```
private XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration buildConfiguration() throws XmppStringprepException {
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder =
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();

    builder.setHost(HOST);
    builder.setPort(PORT);
    builder.setCompressionEnabled(false);
    builder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    builder.setSendPresence(true);
    DomainBareJid serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom(HOST);
    builder.setServiceName(serviceName);

    return builder.build();
}

private XMPPTCPConnection getConnection() throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    Log.e(TAG, "Getting XMPP Connect");
    if (isConnected()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Returning already existing connection");
        return this.connection;
    }

    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        if(this.connection != null){
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection found, trying to connect");
            this.connection.connect();
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "No Connection found, trying to create a new connection");
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = buildConfiguration();
            SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true;
            this.connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
            this.connection.connect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"some issue with getting connection :" + e.getMessage());

    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Connection Properties: " + connection.getHost());
    Log.e(TAG, "Time taken in first time connect: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - l));
    return this.connection;
}

public static XMPP getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (XMPP.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new XMPP();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

public void close() {
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside XMPP close method");
    if (this.connection != null) {
        this.connection.disconnect();
    }
}

private XMPPTCPConnection connectAndLogin(Context context) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside connect and Login");
    if (!isConnected()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection not connected, trying to login and connect");
        try {
            String username = "user1";
            String password = "qwerty123";
            this.connection = getConnection();
            Log.e(TAG, "XMPP username :" + username);
            Log.e(TAG, "XMPP password :" + password);
            this.connection.login(username, password);
            Log.e(TAG, "Connect and Login method, Login successful");
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_LOGGED_IN));
        } catch (XMPPException localXMPPException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in Connect and Login Method1");
            localXMPPException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in Connect and Login Method2");
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in Connect and Login Method3");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in Connect and Login Method4");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in Connect and Login Method5");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in Connect and Login Method6");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside getConnection - Returning connection");
    return this.connection;
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    return (this.connection != null) && (this.connection.isConnected());
}

public EntityFullJid getUser() {
    if (isConnected()) {
        return connection.getUser();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void login(String user, String pass, String username)
        throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException, InterruptedException, XMPPException {
    Log.e(TAG, "inside XMPP getlogin Method");
    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    XMPPTCPConnection connect = getConnection();
    if (connect.isAuthenticated()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "User already logged in");
        return;
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Time taken to connect: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - l));

    l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try{
        connect.login(user, pass);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Issue in login, check the stacktrace");
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Time taken to login: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - l));

    Log.e(TAG, "login step passed");

    PingManager pingManager = PingManager.getInstanceFor(connect);
    pingManager.setPingInterval(10000);

}

public void register(String user, String pass) throws XMPPException, SmackException.NoResponseException, SmackException.NotConnectedException {
    Log.e(TAG, "inside XMPP register method, " + user + " : " + pass);
    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(getConnection());
        accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
        accountManager.createAccount(Localpart.from(user), pass);
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Time taken to register: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - l));
}


public String getUserLocalPart(Context context){
    return  connectAndLogin(context).getUser().getLocalpart().toString();
}

public EntityFullJid getUser(Context context){
    return  connectAndLogin(context).getUser();
}

}
```

error i am getting

```
    E/XMPP-EXAMPLE: Client is not, or no longer, connected. Did you call connect() before login()?
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected. Did you call connect() before login()?  

    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfAppropriate(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:667)  at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:512)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:491)
    at xmpp.XMPP.connectAndLogin(XMPP.java:120)    
    at xmpp.XMPP.removeChatListener(XMPP.java:226) 
    at SplashScreenActivity.onDestroy(SplashScreenActivity.java:255)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7068)   
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1154)    
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4280)    
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4311)     
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)    
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1586)   
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is clear, you are calling connection's `login(...)` before you establish actual connection. It might be caused by loss of connection immediately at connection before calling login. Since you just threw your code at us instead of making a minimal example, I could not follow. Also I have stopped used async task long ago, making it even harder to follow. Here is an example made with MVVM and Coroutine

```
class ChatsViewModel(val app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val chatApp: App = app as App

    fun getConnection(): XMPPTCPConnection? {
        return chatApp.xmppConnection
    }

    fun login(username: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if(chatApp.xmppConnection !=null && chatApp.xmppConnection!!.isAuthenticated) return@launch

        val config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
            .setHostAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.102"))
            .setXmppDomain(JidCreate.domainBareFrom(Constants.JABBER_DOMAIN))
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setPort(5222)
            .enableDefaultDebugger()
            .build()

        val conn = XMPPTCPConnection(config)
        try {
            conn.connect()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
           //conn failed
        }
        if (!conn.isConnected) {
            //alert use is not connected
        }else{
            try {
                conn.login()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //failed to login
            }

            if (!conn.isAuthenticated) {
                //alert user he is not logged in
            }
            else {
                chatApp.xmppConnection = conn

                //do  your thing here. As example we are 
                //going to send presence stanza
                val presence = Presence(Presence.Type.available)
                presence.status = "Gone fishing"
                try {
                    getConnection()?.sendStanza(presence)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    //sending failed
                }
```

and here is how you will use that view model in a fragment (or Activity)

```
class ChatsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var chatsViewModel: ChatsViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        chatsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ChatsViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false)
        return root
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        chatsViewModel.login("xmpp_id_local_part", "123456")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        chatsViewModel.logout()
    }
}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i had gone through the soltuion properly and then the message then i manipulated the code and now it worked thanks mate

Comment: You are welcome! If this answer is useful, plese upvote it!